# GAE + Cloud Storage - Unable to get FileInfo after File is uploaded

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

I am using Flask Web Framework on GAE/Python. After uploading a file to Cloud Storage I want to get a reference to the file so that it can be served.  I can't get the parse_file_info to work. I've searched long and hard and spent over two days trying to make this work. I'm at my wit's end!! You can see my handlers below:

```
@app.route('/upload_form', methods = ['GET'])
def upload_form():
    blobupload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name = 'mystorage')        
    return render_template('upload_form.html', blobupload_url = blobupload_url)     

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def blobupload():    
    file_info = blobstore.parse_file_info(cgi.FieldStorage()['file']) 
    return file_info.gs_object_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is encoded in the payload of uploaded_file you retrieve after uploading a blob. This is example code on how to extract the name:

```
import email
from google.appengine.api.blobstore import blobstore

def extract_cloud_storage_meta_data(file_storage):
    """ Exctract the cloud storage meta data from a file. """
    uploaded_headers = _format_email_headers(file_storage.read())
    storage_object_url = uploaded_headers.get(blobstore.CLOUD_STORAGE_OBJECT_HEADER, None)
    return tuple(_split_storage_url(storage_object_url))

def _format_email_headers(raw_headers):
    """ Returns an email message containing the headers from the raw_headers. """
    message = email.message.Message()
    message.set_payload(raw_headers)
    payload = message.get_payload(decode=True)
    return email.message_from_string(payload)

def _split_storage_url(storage_object_url):
    """ Returns a list containing the bucket id and the object id. """
    return storage_object_url.split("/")[2:4]

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def blobupload():    
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    storage_meta_data = extract_cloud_storage_meta_data(uploaded_file)
    bucket_name, object_name = storage_meta_data
    return object_name
```

Comment: Hey Nik, thanks so much for this!! but, how come you can't use the [fileInfo Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass?hl=en)?

Comment: parse_file_info parses the data from a cgi.FieldStorage. Flask only provides a FileStorage and it was easier to retrieve the information instead of creating a FieldStorage with all the necessary attributes.